# Solr only returning exact matches

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I finally got my Solr working. It indexes posts and I can search it from my site. I have run into one problem though.

If I have an entry as "England", when I search "England" on my site, or "england" I get the result returned. When I search "Eng" it tells me there are no results. I dont want people to have to put in *'s for queries.

My question is this, how do I make it so it doesn't have to be an exact match for results to be returned.

Comment: Append a wildcard character to whatever the user enters. :-) Are you using stemming? I'm not sure what the stem for "England" would be, but "eng" is probably too short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this type of search behavior, you will need to implement the [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory)